# Creating and naming a new file according to a string - gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Total newbie in Gulp, really would like some assistance..

I am trying to name & create a new file using a string that exist in another file. this will give me the name of the white label that was deployed onto the server.

The content of the file that holds the string is (among other things) `{"TITLE":"name_env"}`

name_env should be the new name of the file with the suffix of .web
meaning that the new file would be like this `name_env.web`

What I've came up until now was:

```
    gulp.task('label', function () {
       var str = require('path/to/file/file.json')

       return file('label', str, {src: true})
             .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
        });
```

Am I on the right track ?

Hopefully I've managed to explain myself..

Answer (score 0):

Here's gulp file which will do your task(assuming there's dist folder already exist!!)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('label', function() {
  var buffer = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('path/to/file.json', 'utf8'));
  return fs.writeFile('dist/' + buffer['TITLE'] + '.web' , buffer, { flag: 'wx' }, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("It's saved!");
         });
});
```